# Pinia Store with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am getting an error on my component. Can someone help to solve this? I'm work in vue 3 version. Getting an error: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'counter')" Does anyone have any insights?

This id my code

Pinia Store:

```js
import { ref, computed } from "vue"
import { defineStore } from "pinia"

export const useCounterStore = defineStore("counter", {
  state: () => {
    return {
      counter: 0
    }
  }
})
```

script:

```html
<script setup>
  import { computed, ref } from "@vue/reactivity"
  import { useCounterStore } from "@/stores/counter"

  const storeCounter = useCounterStore()
  console.log(storeCounter)

  console.log(storeCounter.store.counter)
  console.log(storeCounter.counter)
</script>
```

and template:

```html
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <div class="count">{{storeCounter.counter}}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: There's no promise in the code you posted. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem. There's no storeCounter.store.counter, you didn't define store property

Answer (score 1):

One of these console.log statements works, the other does not

```js
console.log(storeCounter.store.counter); // bad syntax, no store object on storeCounter
console.log(storeCounter.counter); // correct
```

All you have to do is delete the offending line.  Simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const useCounterStore = defineStore("counter", {
  state: () => {
    return {
      counter: 0
    }
  }
})
```

I am a bit late, but maybe can help somebody else.

First you should remove that return. Like this your store is defined like `useCounterStore().return.counter`

And this is probably not what you want.

Then remove also this log `console.log(storeCounter.store.counter);` as it will fail due to the `store` that do not exsist. And this is exactly what the error is telling you. It is trying to read a property (`counter`) of undefined (`store`).

If you want to read the store, you should get your states directly, as you correctly do with the second console log, that will work now `console.log(storeCounter.counter);`

So, this is the corrected version of your store:

```
export const useCounterStore = defineStore("counter", {
  state: () => {
    counter: 0
  }
})
```